# mysql selecting from yesterday datetime to today datetime

Tags: mysql

I want to select yesterday datetime to today datetime
for example:

yesterday 4:00pm to today 3:59:59

here is the mssql to do

```
AND s2.created_at  between  Dateadd(dateinterval.Hour,-8,   Dateadd(dateinterval.Day,0,Today)) and Dateadd(dateinterval.second,-1,Dateadd(dateinterval.Hour,-8,    Dateadd(dateinterval.Day,1,Today)))
```

how to do in mysql

Answer (score 0):

My Linux box isn't running at the moment so I can't test it but I think

```
AND s2.created_at >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -8 HOUR) and s2.created_at < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 16 HOUR)
```

By just doing < on the end time, you don't have to do another DATE_ADD.